# Add group and method descriptions in RAML

Tags: raml

I'm trying to generate my API at the moment but having some difficulty adding a description for the first method within a listing group. I can add a description for every other method in a group, just not the first one.

I have attached an image below of how I want it to look but I cannot achieve this using the RAMLtoHTML generator.

[image: Description Issue]

Below is the code I am using in the main file. This file has an include for the file I am having the problem with. I was thinking maybe I could change something in it?

```
#%RAML 0.8
title: Hubs
baseUri: https://apis.3dissue.com/hubsdashboard/api/{version}
version: v1
mediaType: application/json
documentation:
  - title: Getting Started
    content: !include md/getting_started.md
  - title: Overview
    content: !include md/overview.md
  - title: Creating a Hub
    content: !include md/creating_hub.md
  - title: Adding Social Sources to a Hub
    content: !include md/social_sources.md
  - title: Adding an Article to a Hub
    content: !include md/articles.md
traits: !include traits.raml


#Hubs
/hubs: !include calls/hubs.raml
```

This is the file I want to add the description in below. As you can see, I have already added a listing description and if I try to add a method description here, then I get a complaint from the parser that "description" is already defined.

```
is: [appkey]
displayName: User Hubs
description: This group contains methods that will allow you to create, manage, and retrieve details of one or more hubs.
get:
  description: Returns a JSON array containing details of hubs associated with the user account.
  queryParameters:
    page:
      description: The page number to be returned within the paged results. By default, this will return the first page.
      type: number
      default: 1
    page_size:
      description: The number of elements to return per page. By default, a total of 10 elements will be returned. This parameter should be used in combination with the page parameter for setting up paged results.
      type: number
      default: 10
    related:
      description: Determines whether to return related objects. If set to 1, all child elements for each hub in the list will be returned including any sections and sources.
      type: boolean
      default: 0
  body:
    example: !include ../php/getListOfHubs.php
  responses:
    200:
      body:
        application/json:
          example: !include ../json/hubs.json
post:
  description: This method will allow you to create a new hub.
  body:
      example: !include ../php/createHub.php
  responses:
    200:
      body:
        application/json:
          example: !include ../json/hub_create_response.json
/{hub_id}:
  description: The following methods can be used to manage or retrieve details for a given hub.
  uriParameters:
    hub_id:
      description: A string value used to uniquely identify a hub.
      type: string
  get:
    description: Returns a JSON array containing details for the given hub.
    body:
      example: !include ../php/getHub.php
    responses:
      200:
        body:
          application/json:
            example: !include ../json/hub.json
  put:
    description: This method will allow you to update the display name of the given hub.
    body:
      example: !include ../php/updateHub.php
    responses:
      200:
        body:
          application/json:
            example: !include ../json/hub.json
  delete:
    description: This method will allow you to delete the selected hub. Deleting a hub will not remove any sources from your account.
    body:
      example: !include ../php/deleteHub.php
    responses:
      204:
        description: No response body
```

Does anyone have a workaround for this? I have tried adding the description within the first file before the include but get parser errors. I have also tried moving the /hubs declaration within the second file but the only way I can get it to parse is by adding in an extra character to the method call URL which is far from ideal.

Comment: +1  I am very-desperately seeking an answer to this question, as well.  Any help from the community is much-appreciated!